How To Add Dynamic Parameters in Body Data Alongside Static Parameters
I'm having an issue figuring out how to create this scenario. So, I have a request that has numerous dynamic parameters from a previous request in the body response that I need to correlate/parameterize.
These will come with a true or false value as well, but the hardest issue I am discovering is how to make it so that it dynamically populates a POST request later on in the body-data alongside static parameters.
At times it could have 5-10 dynamic parameters that fill up the body data/ payload. Not only that, I am having an issue creating a regular expression that is unique and finding the correct value correlated to it since all the requests have a true or false value. As seen below:
enter image description here
In another request it looks like this if its both true and false: <input type='hidden' value='false'  name='$PD_HIDDENTCANTSHOW_pa3423434234pz$ppxResults$l1$ppyIsVisible'  /><input type='checkbox'  data-test-id='2054534534534'   class='checkbox chkBxCtl' value='true'  name='$PD_HIDDENCANTSHOW_pa3423434234$ppxResults$l1$ppyIsVisible'
While it is can at time have the same parameter name, I will need to add two separate values.
The 1$ppyisInvisible alongside pa3423434234pz is the one that dynamically changes and the number can be 1,5,40,etc.
So how can I iterate through this to be added dynamically and find the correct matches to correlate with the right one?
I having been trying to create a for loop to iterate through all the matches found.
This is HTML body response and not JSON.

While it's quite hard to understand what exactly you're trying to correlate, one thing is obvious: using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea
Consider switching to CSS Selector Extractor or XPath Extractor instead

hi @Ivan G, how would I go about iterating through all the matches I find on a previous request to put it in a POST request for body data/parameter and put it alongside static parameters? Thanks, I will try that Extractor like you suggested.

You can construct request body dynamically using JSR223 PreProcessor and Groovy language, it provides access to sampler shorthand to HTTPSamplerProxy class so you can use addArgument() function for writing the request body on the fly.
